# How to dipose helper disposables using DI in ASP.NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, idisposable

For regular case how to manage disposables such post as [How to correctly and safely dispose of singletons instances registered in the container when an ASP.NET Core app shuts down](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51501578/6734314) explains how to do it.

But I have a slightly different case -- I don't have single instance of some worker `IFoo` like here:

```
interface IFoo : IDisposable // not my case
```

which you know how to dispose, just call `Dispose` on an instance of `IFoo`.

No, my `IFoo` is **not** `IDisposable`:

```
interface IFoo // my case
```

instead of single instance, I have a pair of instances on creation -- `(IFoo,IDisposable)`. When I have to do real work, I use the first item, because there is all logic there, when I am done, I call `Dispose` on the second item.

You could say it is decoupling put at extreme.

And when I am at ASP.NET Core I have problem with DI -- I have a pair like above, I can register `IFoo` with for example `services.AddScoped`, but how to tell `services` that there is distinct/separate `IDisposable` at hand which should be disposed when the work is done and the scope is gone?

Comment: What do you mean you have a pair of instances? Do you mean a pair of *references* to the same instance?

Comment: @madreflection, ok, pair of references to two distinct instances. For simplicity let's say you have some method `Create` which signature is like this `(IFoo,IDisposable) Create()`, so as the effect you can do work (with first item) and when you are done you call `Dispose` on the second item.

Comment: Funny, if that was going to be your response, I was going to suggest exactly what ahydrax just posted in his answer. Try that!

Comment: Although, I should point out that having a reference to just `IDisposable`, especially if that's being injected as such, doesn't make a lot of sense. What are you registering as the concrete class for `IDisposable`?

Comment: @madreflection, there is of course some concrete type, but it is hidden. At hand I have only interfaces, and they are always split, i.e. if there is `IDisposable` involved it is a separate item and the "main" interface never inherits from `IDisposable`.

Comment: If it's just that the the concrete class implements `IFoo` and `IDisposable` without the former inheriting the latter, the container will still take care of disposing it without having to inject a reference to its `IDisposable`.

Comment: @madreflection, thank you, this is good to know. However I cannot firmly rely on it -- (a) it is per case knowledge (b) to be sure I would have to check it out by reflection. So, the info you wrote is valuable for me, but in such cases I won't dare to use it :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a wrapper around `(IFoo, IDisposable)`, let's say:

```
public class DisposableFoo : IDisposable
{
    // Assume FooConcrete implements IFoo and IDisposable
    private readonly FooConcrete _foo;

    public DisposableFoo(FooConcrete fooConcrete) { _foo = fooConcrete; }

    public IFoo Instance => _foo;

    public void Dispose() => _foo.Dispose();
}
```

And then in `Startup.cs` you could do the following to keep your abstractions clean:

```
services.AddTransient<FooConcrete>();
services.AddScoped<DisposableFoo>();
services.AddScoped<IFoo>(ctx => ctx.Resolve<DisposableFoo>.Instance);
```

In this case the underlying `FooConrecte` will be disposed at the end of scope lifetime properly.

Comment: There is no `FooConcrete` but it is still doable, in my case wrapper would have to take the pair and integrate those two. Thank you!